# Embed flash objects using Android

Tags: android, flash, streaming, media

Does anyone know a method to communicate commands and receive events from flash objects using Android?

Flash media objects are quite handy for handling online media streams and I am wondering if we can control those objects to play media from an Android app.

A typical case will be: a flash object embedded in a webview and this webview is loaded by the Android application. The application send "play" commands to the object to start playing the stream and gets "finish" events when reaching the end of the streamed media.

Answer (score 0):

create a webview in your main activity class (or anywhere)

```
var mainW = new WebView(this);
```

enable the needed features of your webview

```
mainW.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
mainW.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
mainW.getSettings().setPluginState(mainW.getSettings().getPluginState().ON);
```

place your html file somewhere which contains the swf and load it's location in webview

```
mainw.loadUrl(url);
```

Comment: But how can I send commands and receive events from the flash object?

Comment: you can call the javascript functions simply loading them as url;

    mainw.loadUrl("Javascript: alert('hello world');");

If you want to call it from the swf, you can use a similair methode (it was loadUrl("Javascript: alert('hello world');"); in AS 2 but i am not sure about AS3 since i don't write AS code anymore)